# Задача из степика

Tags: python

я хочу осуществить ввод списка букв через пробел, чтобы можно было потом с ним работать.  Задача из степика. вот ссылка https://stepik.org/lesson/3373/step/6?unit=956.

> Программа должна считывать одну строку со стандартного ввода и
> выводить для каждого уникального слова в этой строке число его
> повторений (без учёта регистра) в формате "слово количество" (см.
> пример вывода). Порядок вывода слов может быть произвольным, каждое
> уникальное слово должно выводиться только один раз.
>
> Sample Input 1:
>
> ```
> a aa abC aa ac abc bcd a
> ```
>
> Sample Output 1:
>
> ```
> ac 1
> a 2
> abc 2
> bcd 1
> aa 2
> ```
>
> Sample Input 2:
>
> ```
> a A a
> ```
>
> Sample Output 2:
>
> ```
> a 3
> ```

Не знаю сам как это сделать.

```
a aa abC aa ac abc bcd a

n=[i for i in input().split]
n.lower()
print (n)
m={}
for i in n:
    s=n.count(i)
    if i not in m:
        m[i]=s
        print (m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы ваша программа заработала, достаточно исправить первые две строки, заодно объединив их в одну:

```
n = [i for i in input().lower().split()]
```

Пояснение:

- `lower()` надо применять к исходной строке, а не к списку после разбиения (хотя можно её применить потом к каждому элементу этого списка, но проще уж сразу)
- `split()` - это функция, её надо вызывать со скобками

Как напечатать в конце элементы словаря нужным образом попробуйте сами всё-таки догадаться и написать, это просто и можно сделать разными способами.

Comment: спасибо огромное, серьезно

Answer (score 2):

Нужно:

- Привести в нижний регистр (`lower`)
- Разделить по пробелу
- Подсчитать (самое простое через `Counter`)

Пример:

```
from collections import Counter
for w, c in Counter(input().lower().split()).items():
    print(w, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через генератор словарей, потом просто распечатывать пары ключ значение

```
a = [i.lower() for i in input().split()]

b = {i:a.count(i) for i in a}

for key, value in b.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: спасибо, для создания списка a = [i.lower() for i in input().split()] это подойдет же?

Comment: @Mr.White я проверил код на степике - задача его приимает